Airflow Task is getting skipped instead of failure
In this code, task this_will_skip has a bash command
echo hello world; exit 99;
Which should result in the failure of task
But the task is getting skipped
& the task which should run after this_will_skip also gets skipped.

Task 'this_will_skip' should fail

According to the Airflow documentation (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html)

In general a non-zero exit code produces an AirflowException and thus
a task failure. In cases where it is desirable to instead have the
task end in a skipped state, you can exit with code 99 (or with
another exit code if you pass skip_on_exit_code).

That bash command returns a 99 exit code. Hence, it was skipped.
